# process always prints document by default printer

Tags: c#, printing

I have a problem with selecting printer to print my document.

My code is :

```
var filename = @"C:\Users\I\Desktop\test.doc";

PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

pd.PrinterSettings =new PrinterSettings();

    if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
    {
        Process objP = new Process();

        objP.StartInfo.FileName = filename;


        objP.StartInfo.WindowStyle =

        ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hide the window. 

        objP.StartInfo.Verb ="print";

          objP.StartInfo.Arguments ="/p /h \"" + filename + "\" \"" + pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
        objP.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        //true;//!! Don't create a Window. 
        objP.Start();
        //!! Start the process !!// 
        objP.CloseMainWindow();
    }
```

and whatever I choose, `process` always will use default printer, no matter what value of `pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName` is.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the value of `objP.StartInfo.Arguments` what you expect it to be when you step through this code?  Does that work when you key it in manually at a command prompt?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use "PrintTo" instead of "print" for the verb. You already set objP.FileName to the filename so there's no need to get complicated in the arguments. Pass the printer name alone there.

```
var filename = @"C:\Users\I\Desktop\test.doc"; 

PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog(); 

pd.PrinterSettings =new PrinterSettings(); 

if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this)) 
{ 
    Process objP = new Process(); 

    objP.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    objP.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hide the window.
    objP.StartInfo.Verb ="PrintTo";
    objP.StartInfo.Arguments = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
    objP.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; 
    //true;//!! Don't create a Window.  

    objP.Start(); 
    //!! Start the process !!//  

    objP.CloseMainWindow(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `pd.PrinterSettings =new PrinterSettings();` to read something like this:

```
pd.PrinterSettings =new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings;
```

By default when you create an instance of printer settings it returns the  default printer name just an fyi... you can then try something like this

```
//sudu code
foreach(string strPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
 // or unless you know the name of the printer then skip this and assign it to the code above
}
```